# Where to find the $PEERID used in Chainlink Offchain Reporting Jobs .toml file --> P2P BootstrapPeers =[...]

Tags: chainlink, toml

Where can the $PEERID be found, which is used in Chainlink Offchain Reporting Jobs .toml file
--> P2P BootstrapPeers =[...] ?

This is the link to Offchain Reporting Jobs in Chainlink:
https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/types/offchain-reporting/

Question concerning the OCR toml job specification:

The syntax of p2pBootstrapPeer is the following:
/dns4/$DNS/tcp/$PORT/p2p/$PEERID

---> where in my specifications can I find the $PEERID ?

In the Chainlink Nodeoperator GUI? If yes, where exactly?
If not, where else? (edited)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Couple ways to set this:

1. You can manually set it via an env_car called P2P_PEER_ID. If you don't override it, it will try use this value by default
2. As per the docs you linked, set the p2pPeerID value in your job spec, which will become the $PEERID. eg

   p2pPeerID          = "12D3KooWPjceQrSwdWXPyLLeABRXmuqt69Rg3sBYbU1Nft9HyQ6X"

Comment: and how can the $PORT be set? 
Also via the .env file? 
If yes, which port is the best to choose? 

Besides, the docs specify that if I set P2P_LISTEN_PORT=none       
then Chainlink will randomly select a different port each time it boots. 
Is this correct?